# Java EE application is deployed on JBoss 7, but cannot be opened in browser

Tags: jakarta-ee, deployment, jboss

I want to run my java ee application on an local JBoss 7 Server. I deployed the application from eclipse and it seems that it worked. When i log into the jboss console admin console in the browser it shows that the war file is deployed and enabled. When i try to access my app from the browser over localhost:8080/JbossTest, i receive a Resource not found 404 error. I also tried to access the index.html/.xhtml/jsp files but nothing worked.

Comment: A 404 simply means that URL is wrong and/or that the target resource doesn't exist at all. As you seem to be randomly guessing file extensions it look like that you don't have any resource at all. Let's take a step back: which files exactly do you have in the web root of your project? Why exactly didn't you just request those files but you instead guessed some random index URLs?

Comment: Hey, all of those files exist in my root folder. Sorry i should have mentioned this. And the url should exist to because the server is running on the local host.

Comment: Can you post your web.xml, and may be the war contents?

Comment: Are you sure you are running on default ports? (don't have offset -100, etc...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you first look standalone\log\server.log .The log if has something error.
If no error,you can see context=\yourAppPath